# DotNetOpenAuth OAuth2 Linked-In Example

Tags: linkedin-api, dotnetopenauth

I am using DotNetOpenAuth and upgrading from OAuth to OAuth2 accessing www.linkedin.com's API.
Linked-In has changed where you pass parameters like scope - it moved it to the first call when requesting the access token.  Does anyone have any sample calling and setup code?  Specifically, what values do you set for AccessTokenEndpoint, RequestTokenEndpoint, UserAuthorizationEndpoint, TamperProtectionElements and ProtocolVersion?  Also where to set the Linked-In API Key and Secret Key?  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't exactly an answer but you'll find a FaceBook sample using OAuth2.

1. Download the DotNetOpenAuth Binaries zip file.
2. Open \DotNetOpenAuth-4.3.0.13117\Samples\Samples.sln.
3. Open the OAuth2\OAuthClient project and look at Facebook.aspx.cs
4. Open the DotNetOpenAuth.ApplicationBlock project and look at \Facebook\FacebookClient.cs.